# static constexpr member storage

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

If I write a trait like this,

```
template <typename T>
struct is_int {
  static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct is_int<int> {
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

Is the `value` actually stored in memory when the program runs? For example, if I use this trait on a million different types, does the program use 1 MB of memory to store these values?

To paraphrase, is there still any advantage to using

```
template <typename T>
struct is_int {
  enum { value = 0; }
};

template <>
struct is_int<int> {
  enum { value = 1; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, a compiler will map multiple equal constants onto each other, so all the classes/instances would share a single byte (or four byte, or whatever).

Depending on the usage of a constants's value (in the code it is referred to), the compiler might remove it completely as 'unnecessary intermediate', because it can derive the outcomes of the `IF`'s or wherever it is used directly (statically).